# Can I set `ng-repeat` object as `model` to share the details?

Tags: angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to display a property of an `array`. and i need further details to share with other elements to from this array. but the element not nested inside of the `ng-repeat`.

In this case is it possible to set the `array` object as a `model` to share the details to other elements?

here is my code :

```
<ul>

    <li ng-click="activate(item)" ng-model="item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active : active == item}">

      <span ng-if="item == active"> 
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <!-- when active nested under span -->
      </span>
      <!-- else without nesting the span -->
      <span ng-if="item !== active">{{item.name}}</span>

    </li>

  </ul>

  <h1>{{item.age}}</h1> //i am trying to fetch model info here
```

Comment: Not clear what the problem is, you already have activate function, so you can pass active item and use it outside of the ngRepeat.

Comment: `ng-model` doesn't work with `li` element. You should use it with inputs elements.

Comment: as like `dfsq` say, it will work. but is that the only way to do it? the reason why i asking is, there is no.of property need to define in the `active` instead if i can consume directly then that would be easier.

Comment: @dfsq / alberto - can you help me to use the `Rohit Kumar` answer? and see my common on his reply too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make ng-click set the item to a scope variable:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'a',
    age: 12
  }, {
    name: 'b',
    age: 15
  }];
  $scope.activate = function(item) {
    $scope.active = item;
  };
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="activate(item)" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active : active == item}">
      <span ng-if="item == active"> 
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <!-- when active nested under span -->
      </span>
      <!-- else without nesting the span -->
      <span ng-if="item !== active">{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>{{active.age}}</h1>
</div>
```